# How to scrape data from web page?

Tags: php, web-scraping

I need to show some news from web page, so I need to extract data from web site. But I am unable to extract data as the following code:

```
$html=file_get_html("http://listverse.com/2014/12/01/10-times-us-foreign-policy-was-wildly-inconsistent/");
     foreach($html->find('article h2') as $element)
     {
        echo "<h2>".$element->plaintext."</h2>"."<br>";

        foreach ($html->find('article h2 p') as $element1) {

            echo "<pre>";print_r($element1->plaintext );
        }
```

But I got correct header but each paragraph is redundant.

Comment: This is really a dirty method to get the data from that news website. When you look into the source code you can see there is a .rss feed. Why don't you use that one to fetch the data? 
For example: http://listverse.com/feed/

And the one specific for your post:
http://listverse.com/2014/12/01/10-times-us-foreign-policy-was-wildly-inconsistent/feed/

Comment: rss does not have complete details

Comment: Note that copying news of another website and republishing it will probably violate copyright.

Comment: i am not want to republish news i am want read news with out any GUI

Answer (score 1):

The paragraphs **follow** the headings, they aren't descendants of them (and HTML doesn't allow paragraphs to descend from headings anyway).

Having got the headings, you need to look at their siblings (e.g. looping over them until you get one that isn't a paragraph or is another heading).

Comment: there is any solution for that

Comment: Yes. See the second paragraph of the answer.